# Open GPKG embedded layers in python

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona, geopackage

I have a gpkg with multiple tables, and I am trying to load it with geopandas:

```
import geopandas as gpd
filename = '~/example.gpkg'
gdf = gpd.read_file(filename)'
```

This returns the first table/layer in the gpkg. Is there any way to access the other layer, i.e. something like:

```
filename = '~/example.gpkg|second_table'
```

I'm guessing I might need to use fiona directly, but couldn't figure it out from the docs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the layer parameter:

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(r'C:\folder\geopackage.gpkg', layer='somelayername')
```

`read_file` uses fiona.open, see: [fiona.open docs](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiona.html#fiona.open)